# how to add number to the end of the string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I did various implementations but they take a long time
Can anyone give us the best implementation?
For example, add a ten-digit number to the end of a string
I did not find a good answer on the Internet

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
std::string a="string";
long n=1703705707;
a.append(std::to_string(n)); //becomes "string1703705707"
```

Comment: yes i use it but my compiler say (to_string) was not decradeble in this scope!
is there another way??

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Are you trying to do it in global scope I mean outside of functions? Try to do that in main() or something.

Comment: my code is so long about 130 line !